# Optimize non-trivial function on tensors

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I am looking for a way to speed up the specific operation on tensors in PyTorch. Since it is a general operation on matrices, I am open to answers in NumPy as well.

Let's say I have a tensor with values from 0 to N-1 (N=4) where each value repeats the same number of times (R=2).

```
import torch
x = torch.Tensor([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3])
```

In this case, it is sorted, but any permutation of `x` is also in the set of considered tensors `X`.

I am getting an input tensor with values from 0 to N-1 but without any constraints on the repetition.

```
z = torch.tensor([3, 2, 3, 0, 2, 3, 1, 2])
```

And I would like to find an efficient implementation of `foo` such that `y = foo(z)`. `y` should be some permutation of `x` (from the set `X`) that tries to do as few changes in `z` as possible (in terms of Hamming distance), for example

```
y = torch.tensor([3, 2, 3, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1])
```

The trivial solution is to keep counting the number elements with the same value, but it is extremely inefficient to process elements one-by-one for larger tensors:

```
def foo(z):
    R = 2
    N = 4
    counters = [0] * N
    # first, we replace extra elements with -1
    y = []
    for elem in z:
        if counters[elem] < R:
            counters[elem] += 1
            y.append(elem)
        else:
            y.append(-1)
    y = torch.tensor(y)
    assert torch.equal(y, torch.tensor([3, 2, 3, 0, 2, -1, 1, -1]))
    # second, we replace -1 by "unfilled" counters
    for i in range(len(y)):
        if y[i] == -1:
            first_unfilled = [n for n in range(N) if counters[n] < R][0]
            counters[first_unfilled] += 1
            y[i] = first_unfilled
    return y
assert torch.equal(y, foo(z))
```

Comment: This seems a bit underspecified. The example `x` is sorted and has contiguous values starting at 0. I.e. it would be completely specified by the repetition count 2 and upper limit 3. And to count the minimal number of changes, we need the set of possible changes. Is `swap two elements of z` in that set? "Increment"? "Replace with new value"? See "Levenshtein distance" for a standard measure, which has Python implementations

Comment: @MSalters Thanks for pointing to these issues! I tried to clarify the text of the question. Yes, x is fully specified by the repetition count 2 and upper limit 3. "swap two elements of z" is not in the set, "replace with new value" is. I believe the proper definition for it is the Hamming Distance. There are standard Python implementations for these things, but I didn't find any native to numpy or pytorch. I guess that pure python implementations will be slow for big tensors too.